# Prove that sec 2x + tan 2x = tan (x + pi/4)

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to figure out how to do this question, and no matter what I do, I can't seem to the solution. Below is my working so far,

LHS =

= sec 2x + tan 2x
= 1/cos2x + sin2x/cos2x
= 1+sin2x/cos2x

I've tried double angle (albeit, most likely incorrectly, if I keep failing to reach a solution). I've also tried comp. angles etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A similar question that may help: [Prove this identity: $ \tan(2x)-\sec(2x) =\tan(x-\pi/4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762487/prove-this-identity-tan2x-sec2x-tanx-pi-4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand side can be written as $$\frac{1+\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}$$
the right-hand side as $$\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$$ multiply numerator and denominator of the last term by $$\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

We expand the RHS to get $$\frac{\tan x + \tan \frac{\pi}{4}}{1 - \tan x \tan \frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{\tan x + 1}{1 - \tan x} = \frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+1}{1 - \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} = \frac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x - \sin x},$$
and we now multiply top and bottom by $\cos x + \sin x$ to obtain $$\frac{\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x + 2 \sin x \cos x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x} = \frac{1+2 \sin x \cos x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}=\frac{1+\sin 2x}{\cos 2x},$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Set $t=\tan x$ and use the double-angle formulæ (the first one is valid for $x\not\equiv \pm\frac\pi 4\bmod\pi$):
$$\tan 2x=\frac{2t}{1-t^2},\qquad \cos 2x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: set $x+\pi/4=y$, so the left-hand side becomes
$$
\frac{1+\sin(2y-\pi/2)}{\cos(2y-\pi/2)}=\frac{1-\cos2y}{\sin2y}
$$
Now use the duplication formulas…